# React Native / Redux - rendering list of items, how to request data by id for each item to show details and not override previous requested data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I render a list of items. On click (on each item), I am showing a details view of that item by making an api request by Id. The problem is that when I click on lets say Item1 and Item 2, the object I receive for Item2 'overrides' Item1'- meaning I always show same details data for all items, which makes sense because I re-render with the newly requested data (item2 for example). Ive been thinking and trying to find my mistake for so long now, any help would be deeply appreciated !!!!!!!!!!

my action:

```
export const fetchItem = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ITEM})
        return ItemAPI.getItem(id)
            .then(item => {
                dispatch({type: FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS, payload: item})
            })

    }
}
```

reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {

case FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        item: action.payload
    }
}
```

my container:

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchItems()
    }
    getItem = (id) => {
        this.props.fetchItem(id)
    }
    renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <WatchedItem
            itemSummary={item}
            itemDetails={this.props.item}
            getItem={this.getItem}
        />
    )
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.items}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: _.map(_.values(state.watchList.items), "item"),
        item: state.watchList.item
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
    {fetchItems, fetchItem})(AppContainer)
```

Item:

```
export default class WatchedItem extends React.Component {
    state = {
        showDetailView: false
    }    
    getItem = () => {
        this.props.getCoin(this.props.itemSummary.id)
        this.setState({
            showDetailView: !this.state.showDetailView
        })
    }    
    render() {
        const {itemDetails, itemSummary: {name, symbol}} = this.props;
        return (
            <View>
                <View>                     
                    <Text> {name} </Text>
// HERE IS THE PROBLEM. WHEN I CLICK ON MULTIPLE ITEMS, THE DETAILS ARE SHOWN FOR ALL BUT ONLY WITH LATEST FETCHED ITEM
                    <Button onPress={this.getItem}>Show Details</Button>
                </View>
                <View>
                    {this.state.showDetailView ? <WatchedItemDetailView item={itemDetails}/> : null}
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

the data looks about like this:

```
items: [{id:1, name: "item1"}, {id:2, name: "item2"}, ...]

item: {id:1, name: "item1", symbol: "xxx", somethingelse: "else",...}
```

Ps. I cannot already save all the detailsinfo of Item in "items", because that data constantly changes, so I do need to request it seperate to get current data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in how you're storing the items, i.e you're only saving one under the `item` key. Instead you could save all of them items as an object, e.g.

```
case FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        items: {
            ...state.items,
            [action.payload.id]: action.payload
        }
    }
}
```

(it wasn't clear from your question what the `state.watchList` data looked like, propose changing it to just an id).

```
mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: Object.values(state.items),
        item: state.items[state.watchList.id]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So I do have them all saved (incl. the full object) which is rendered somewhere else. The items (this.props.items) is a list of saved items by the user (with limited data(just name, id that never updates)). I intentionally dont save all data for each item but instead make the api request by id, because the data always changes (except name, id) so I want to get the current one. If I didnt make the api request but instead did: [action.payload.id]: action.payload - wouldnt I receive 'old' data?